# C# WPF Composite transform issues

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, transform, composite

Having issues with handling translate and rotate transformations at the same time.
I have just started trying to build asteroids and this is my first time programming a WPF application.

My player ship is represented by a Polygon object and it performs rotate and translate on keydown events.

My rotate transform works as expected INDIVIDUALLY.
the main issue is that once I translate and then try to rotate again, the rotate transform tries to rotate around the previous point, even though its specified to get the new centerX and centerY coordinates.

The translate transform seems to move the Polygon roughly +50x and +50y (even though the coordinates used in the transformation prove otherwise) and then it correctly moves in the direction specified by the rotation.

Thanks in advance for any help that someone can give me!

**Heres my C#**:

```
public void handleRotate(KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        this.rotate(10);
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.Left)
    {
        this.rotate(-10);
    }

}

public void handleUpDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        this.move();
    }
}

public double convertToRadians(double angle)
{
    return (Math.PI / 180) * (angle - 90);
}

public void move()
{
    double radians = convertToRadians(playerShip.getHeading());
    double xMovement = Math.Cos(radians) * 10;
    double yMovement = Math.Sin(radians) * 10;

    playerShip.setShipCenterX(xMovement += playerShip.getShipCenterX());
    playerShip.setShipCenterY(yMovement += playerShip.getShipCenterY());
    MessageBox.Show("Heading: " + playerShip.getHeading().ToString() + " centerx: " + playerShip.getShipCenterX().ToString() + " centery: " + playerShip.getShipCenterY().ToString());
    TranslateTransform translate = new TranslateTransform(xMovement, yMovement);
    theShipShape.RenderTransform = translate;

}

public void rotate(double rotation)
{
    double newHeading = playerShip.getHeading() + rotation;
    RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform(newHeading, playerShip.getShipCenterX(), playerShip.getShipCenterY());
    MessageBox.Show("Heading: " + newHeading.ToString() + " centerx: " + playerShip.getShipCenterX().ToString() + " centery: " + playerShip.getShipCenterY().ToString());
    theShipShape.RenderTransform = rotate;
    playerShip.setHeading(newHeading);
}
```

}

**Heres my xaml**:

```
<Window x:Name="GameWindow" x:Class="AsteroidsAttempt2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Canvas x:Name="GameCanvas" Focusable="True" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="320" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517" KeyDown="GameCanvas_KeyDown"/>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Render Transforms are applied at rendering and are not altering the state of the object itself. What you need is a TransformGroup if you want to apply consequtive translations. That one has a Children property to which you can add Transforms with the order you wish them to execute, so you can translate, then rorate, then translate again etc.

Of course if many of them accumulate as children it might take some time to calculate the resulting TransformMatrix. In that case you might want to periodically tell the TransformGroup to give you a TransformMatrix (if it doesn't have such method search for some implementation on the net) that you could then use as the only children of the TransformGroup (remove the previous ones). Then you start again adding more children like TranslateTransform etc. and then later on if say you reach 10 transforms, you remove them again and add the equivalent MatrixTransform for all of them as the first child of TransformGroup and so on...